# Running Rails console on heroku, in sandbox mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

Couldn't find it in the docs, nor on SO, but is there a way to run the Rails (3.2.x) console in sandbox mode on heroku (Celadon Cedar), equivalent to

```
rails console --sandbox
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For a more "the Heroku way" alternative, `heroku run console --sandbox` does the trick as well:

```
$ heroku run console --sandbox
Running `console --sandbox` attached to terminal... up, run.6024

[...]

Loading production environment in sandbox (Rails 3.2.12)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0>
```

Comment: As at September 2023, this no longer works. I get `Error: Nonexistent flag: --sandbox`

Answer (score 3):

If you're here because `rails console --sandbox` stopped working for you as of 09/23, you'll need to explicitly add quotes around your rails command to get Heroku to recognize it.

`heroku run 'rails console --sandbox' -a your-app`