# Rails first_or_create adds (1=2) to query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

While running development code through Heroku console in sandbox mode, I use first_or_create to test for existence of a record:

```
Right.where(:language           => language          ).
      where(:work_id            => work_id           ).
      where(:contact_id         => contact_id        ).
      first_or_create!
```

The query to test for existence of the record gets an extra predicate (1=2) added to it, so the record is not found.

```
SELECT "rights".* FROM "rights" WHERE "rights"."language" = 'ger' AND "rights"."work_id" = 625 AND "rights"."contact_id" = 1435 AND (1 = 2) LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone suggest how I track down the source of this -- is it a sandbox mode thing, perhaps?

Edit: Sandbox mode being invoked by:

```
heroku run console -s --app my-app-name
```

[Running Rails console on heroku, in sandbox mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527383/running-rails-console-on-heroku-in-sandbox-mode)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Sandbox mode'?

Comment: @NeilMiddleton edited Q to include details

Answer (score 2):

OK, mystery solved.

The first_or_create was being invoked from a method into which arguments were passed for a number of attributes. Something like:

```
def get_right(language,work_id,contact_id,terms)
  right = Right.where(:language           => language          ).
                where(:work_id            => work_id           ).
                where(:terms              => terms             ).
                where(:contact_id         => contact_id        ).
                first_or_create!
  right.id
end
```

When the method was called the terms argument was being passed as {} instead of nil.

Apparently activerecord's method of dealing with stupidity like that is to remove the predicate on the offending column (terms) in the query and append a (1 = 2) predicate instead.

I can't say that I wouldn't rather encounter an error :(

Comment: This was actually introduced [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/30a576fa145a8a7d7f68ac295addb24465baf39a). It prevents a security issue, where sending an empty hash were allowing you to do SQL injection. This is not an error, it's actually the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the info -- is that following a particular Rails philosophy thing, this way of making a "silent failure" rather than throwing an error?

Comment: This is not considered as an error, but a feature. Querying with a hash allows you to specify some equality checks on fields. An empty hash automatically returns no record.