# ActiveRecord Uniqueness Constraint Returning Record Exists When It Doesn't

Tags: activerecord

I'm getting this output:

```
Patient Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."chrono_id" = 5668276 LIMIT 1
```

I know that a patient record with a chrono_id of that number does not exist, but I went to the console to check anyway.

```
Patient.where(chrono_id: 5668276)
Patient Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."chrono_id" = 5668276
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Console agrees with me.

My model validation looks like

```
validates_uniqueness_of :chrono_id, :allow_blank => true, :allow_nil => true
```

If I try to create the patient in the console, I get the same error

```
Patient.create(chrono_id: 5668276, first_name: "a", last_name: "a", dob: "1988/12/11")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Patient Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."chrono_id" = 5668276 LIMIT 1
```

Which is reassuring because at least it means it isn't an environment issue.

I tried to recreate the exact sql request that was coming back with a result so I could see the result and figure out when/how it was created

```
a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT 1 AS one FROM patients WHERE patients.chrono_id = 5668276 LIMIT 1")
   (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM patients WHERE patients.chrono_id = 5668276 LIMIT 1

 => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fe0d343f650 @columns=["one"], @rows=[], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={"one"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Integer:0x007fe0cef8bcc0>}>
```

There are no row values returned so I remain confused. Any ideas?

**Update**

I had a typo that was entering one of the other required fields as nil. For some reason the Activerecord error didn't tell me there was an issue with this field but threw this unique_record issue instead.

**Update 2**
The complete message in the logs was

```
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Patient Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."chrono_id" = 5669845 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Just to clear up a possible misunderstanding, the line emitted to the log file that begins "Patient Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS ..." is only noting the execution of the query used to detect a uniqueness violation, not that a violation was detected. If a violation was detected it would probably be followed by another line with a timing in ms and "ROLLBACK". If there was no ROLLBACK then I'd suspect that the uniqueness validation on Patient chorine_id was not the cause.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; sorry I wasn't clearer about the next line being a rollback which is why I assumed the previous line was an error message. I didn't realize it was just a log that the check had occurred. It seems to me that there could have been no error message delivered at all then, just an announcement of a rollback. Does this seem right or do rollbacks always have an associated logged error?

Comment: The presence of a ROLLBACK is usually what I look for in determining the cause of a database-based (?) validation failure (rather than a number being out of range, or summit detectable within Rails). It often demonstrates also exactly what check is being made -- is there a scope being applied on a uniqueness validation, for example. If there's a logged error statement it might appear below ("ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Name has already been taken, Code has already been taken)" ... that sort of thing) but not sure if that would always be the case -- maybe version dependent?

Comment: Being a database type of person, checking the SQL might appeal to me more than most -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937390/rails-first-or-create-adds-1-2-to-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a typo that was entering one of the other required fields as nil. A comment on my original post pointed out that the 'error' I referenced was actually just a log that a uniqueness check was run, not that it has returned positive despite the next line being a rollback.

I encourage anyone to read the comments on the main post if running into a similar issue. If summarized by the poster as an answer, I'll choose that as the answer to the question.